# hover event on overlapping divs is not working

Tags: html, css, pie-chart

I am trying to make a piechart by rotating the overlapping divs. I need to take action on mouseover or hover. Every thing is working fine if the sum of the first and last slice is 180deg or greater than 180deg.
But it stops taking hover event when the sum goes below.
Please visit
http://jsfiddle.net/fjBfE/

here when i do mouseover on the green slice-- at some points its mouseover is not working and at some points its working.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with the z-index of adjacent slices.

What happens if you add some sort of javascript "hover:not {z-index = 0}" to each slice? (excuse the pseudo-code)

Comment: I've isolated it to the olive green overlapping (somehow) the green (but not the blue or the orange), but cannot find the right solution to correct it.

Comment: Swati I think you haven't found your solution this way. Can you go with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this inherent problem with this model. if you want to keep div elements in loop, you have to

1. either, add them in increasing order keeping their z-index same
2. or, add them in any order but with their z-index increasing.

Here's what I meant:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
     .pieContainer{
     position:relative;
     }
 .pie {
          position: absolute;
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
       /*  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
          -o-border-radius: 150px;
         border-radius: 150px;
/*         */ clip: rect(0px, 300px, 150px, 150px);
     }

     #pie1{
        background-color:#ff0000;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
          z-index:100;
    }
    #pie2{
        background-color:#00ff00;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(60deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(60deg);
          transform:rotate(60deg);
          z-index:100;
    }
    #pie3{
        background-color:#0000ff;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(120deg);
          transform:rotate(120deg);
          z-index:100;
    }
    #pie4{
        background-color:#ffff00;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
          transform:rotate(180deg);
          z-index:100;
    }
    #pie5{
        background-color:#ff00ff;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(240deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(240deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(240deg);
          transform:rotate(240deg);
          z-index:100;
    }
    #pie6{
        background-color:orange;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(300deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(300deg);
          transform:rotate(300deg);

          z-index:100;
    }
    /
    /*#pie7{
    position:absolute;
        width:50px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
        z-index:101;
        left:150px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 150px;

    }*/
    .pie{z-index:1;}

    .pie:hover{
        background-color:#000000;

        }
        #idea{-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:700px;
        z-index:1000;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pieContainer">
     <div class="pieBackground"></div>
     <div id="pie1" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie2" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie3" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie4" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie5" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie6" class="pie"></div>
     <div id="pie7"></div>
</div>
<div id="idea">idea</div>
</body>
</html>
```

remove this comment in the beginning of the code: `/*  -moz-border-radius: 150px;` and things will look circular.

http://jsfiddle.net/KzG2Z/ : square one

http://jsfiddle.net/KzG2Z/1/  : circular one

If you can use there are pretty cool JS solutions that you can use.

http://www.artetics.com/Articles/using-various-javascript-libraries-to-create-pie-chart

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

In the end what you have tried to do is sort of close circuit design, it closes. (couldn't help myself) (circuit was redundant)

Also there are some issues, if you want to dynamically do this, you are cornered even before you tackle that because you aren't using JS | jQuery, if you have been, there are APIs... you know. (again)